# JQuery variable always having same value

Tags: jquery, ajax, twig

I am returning a list of anchors using a loop in TWIG:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show_post_anchor" data-post-id="{{ entity.id }}">{{ entity.id }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The final goal is to load some information in a div using AJAX/jquery onclick on the anchor

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('a.show_post_anchor').click(function(e){

      var id= $("a.show_post_anchor").attr("data-post-id");
      alert(id);


       e.preventDefault();
       return false;

   });
  });
```

The problem is that the alert is always returning the same value onclick on different anchors, even if the anchors are displayed correctly (with different data-post-id values). I really don't understand where the problem  comes from even after hours of thinking, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `var id = $(this).attr("data-post-id");` instead `var id =$("a.show_post_anchor").attr("data-post-id");`

Comment: @DKM Please to post it as an asnwer since it is perfectly working. It will also be better to give some details explaining the differenc ebetween the two ways.Thank you very much.

Comment: @DKM, I am waiting for some  minutes to be able to accept. many thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

As your all `<a>` tags have `.show_post_anchor` class and you were using `$('a.show_post_anchor')` so in DOM it will look for the class `.show_post_anchor` at first it will get only first value, And `$(this)` represents the current clicked object.

```
 $('a.show_post_anchor').click(function(e){
      var id= $(this).attr("data-post-id");
      alert(id);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDELc/)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to address the exact element that was clicked, so instead of:

```
var id= $("a.show_post_anchor").attr("data-post-id");
```

write:

```
var id= $(this).attr("data-post-id");
```

That should solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the selector again, which picks the first match (the first ID), instead of the instance of the selector, like this:

```
var id= $(this).attr("data-post-id");
```

Comment: jQuery can be frustrating that way, it all looks right and just doesn't work. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id= $("a.show_post_anchor").attr("data-post-id");
```

it's not getting what anchor your are clicking, you need to give the value from e

should be

```
    var id= $(this).attr("data-post-id");
```